# Заменить картинку на текст в View

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Подскажите, как заменить картинку,которая загружается с ресурсов таким образом :

```
//****Здесь получаю этот обьект, Картинка прописаная в XML коде странице
        View bodyText = view.findViewById(R.id.downloadTap);

        //Check for audio downloading progress
        if (checkForExists(p) || p.url == null) {
            p.progress = 100;
            //*****здесь нужно поменять на другую картинку
            bodyText.setClickable(false);
        } else if (p.progress == 0) {
            p.progress = 0;
            bodyText.setClickable(true);
        }else{
            //*****здесь нужно менять текст
        }
```

Там где иконка для скачивания(справа), нужно её менять:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Задайте для кнопки `ID`.
2. Найдите её в коде по `ID` методом `findViewById`
3. Присвойте ей другую картинку методом `setImageResource` или `setImageDrawable`